# Condensed citation of multiple GitHub issues

Tags: citations, citation-style

I have submitted around ~12 bug reports and want to cite this factoid in my paper. But I don't want to cite 12 different links for each GitHub issue. The links all have this common prefix:

`https://github.com/ConsenSys/mythril/issues/`

So, when I added the link in my citation, I was thinking of using `https://github.com/ConsenSys/mythril/issues/[584, 1270, 1232, 1235, 1293, 1294, 988, 1300, 1303, 1291, 1238, 1295]`.

There is no single suggested citation format (e.g., MLA, APA, IEEE), but an answer that somewhat, but not quite, resembles my query is [here](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2014/11/how-to-cite-multiple-pages-from-the-same-website.html). Is there any documentation that anyone could point me to? If not, I will go with that answer.

Comment: Could you perhaps cite the issues page and expand on what issues you posted in a footnote?

Comment: I like it. I haven't so far used footnotes, but that seems like it would be better than what I have going right now. Thanks!

Comment: Is it too much to ask why you are citing bug tickets in your paper? Anyway, offering the numbers alone would be enough for someone to follow up.

Comment: Its a fair question. I took on an overly narrative tone and have to dial it back, according to my adviser, so I may actually decide to not include that. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @AaronBrick Generally, citing issue reports is a good idea if it allows readers to verify and reproduce the paper's findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in a [comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/143512/condense-citation#comment380893_143512), "the numbers alone would be enough." Those numbers can appear in the main body, e.g.,

*During the course of this research, twelve bugs were reported for the*  mythril *security analysis software. (Those reports are numbered 584, 1270, 1232, 1235, 1293, 1294, 988, 1300, 1303, 1291, 1238, and 1295, all of which are accessibly from the following url: \url{https://github.com/ConsenSys/mythril/issues/}.)*

You could push the bracketed details to a footnote, since they are less interesting. You could also summarise any particularly interesting reports, perhaps you've already done that.